# Linux digital recording — Audacity or Ardour?

Tags: software

We're evaluating options for a live recording setup in a church. Because the budget is tight, we're looking at running Linux with two Delta 1010's.

So far I've [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and [Ardour](http://ardour.org/). So far I'm leaning towards Ardour because it's got a more familiar environment for our uses, and it's bundled with a flavour of Ubuntu.

What other pieces of software are out there for Linux?

Comment: After converting to Linux specifically for the purpose of producing music, and using it for several years, I'd recommend not using it at all.  Linux audio is a nightmare, and really only appropriate if you have no money, a lot of idealism, and aren't a professional.  Windows or Mac are much more reliable for audio.

Comment: @endolith - No Money: Check. Idealism: Check (it is a church, after all). Not a professional: Check.

Comment: Have fun, then.  :)  Don't say I didn't warn you.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992361 http://whylinuxsucks.org/linux-sound-cacophony-confusion http://linuxhaters.blogspot.com/2008/06/tada.html http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2007/05/welcome_to_the_jungle.html

Comment: @endolith - all good, I'm not the one that's going to have to use it every week :)

Comment: Neither. Use Audition (Cool Edit) and Wine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe Audacity is intended for stereo recording and basic editing.

Ardour is aimed at the traditional DAW market, like other products such as Sonar & ProTools.

If you are looking to produce a podcast, Audacity is probably the best tool.
If you are looking to produce a musical album, Ardour is probably the best tool.

Answer (score 3):

Audacity's recording capabilities are very very limited, and it can't record multiple tracks simultaneously (one 5.1 track - yes, 2 solo voices - no). It's only suitable for recording radio shows or lp/cassette conversions or may be your church program live, one mic non-stop.

Ardour works great. probably the best choice, and there's *Jokosher*

*Reaper* can be made to work in linux. Not free, but uncrippled, unexpiring trial version available.

Answer (score 2):

Rosegarden is an alternative http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/